# Background image overflowing out of div

Tags: html, css

I would like the image declared in `bg` to fit to the `container-fluid` but it is overflowing. See https://www.soundshelter.net/ for live.

The goal is to have the text over the top of the image, so `opacity` and `blur` can be applied to the image and not affect the text.

I have tried using `overflow:hidden;` but this is being ignored.

Edit: this also exists if I remove the background images and use a `background-color` instead.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="bg"></div>
   <div class="row hero_header">
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg /*this is the background image*/
  {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: url("/images/record_wall_orig_two.jpg") 0px 0px;
      background-size:cover;
      height:100vh;
      background-color: black;
      -webkit-filter:  blur(8px); / Chrome, Safari, Opera /
      filter:  blur(8px);



  }
```

Comment: have you tried adding max-width and max-height attributes to the bg class?

Comment: I haved @DhavalChheda but it screwed with the responsive of the site on mobile (using Bootstrap)

Comment: This can be easily achieve by only using bootstrap jumbotron class. then you can set the jumbotron css background to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position relative to the parent of ".bg" and overflow hidden. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check and try the code below. Hope it could help and give you an idea.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more »</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/28209/pexels-photo-28209-large.jpg") center;
  background-color: black;


}

p {
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

The working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex9qkgxL/).